# Handling arguments in specified order in /usr/bin/printf or Bash printf

Tags: bash, printf

Preamble. I know that in the `C` language, the `printf` function allows to do this:

```
printf('%2$s %2$s %1$s %1$s', 'World', 'Hello');
```

Output: `Hello Hello World World`

But in GNU Bash it seems this feature is not supported:

```
printf '%2$s %2$s %1$s %1$s' 'World' 'Hello'
```

Output: `bash: printf: $': invalid format character`

I also tried using the local `/usr/bin/printf`:

```
/usr/bin/printf '%2$s %2$s %1$s %1$s' 'World' 'Hello'
```

Output: `/usr/bin/printf: %2$: invalid conversion specification`

How to obtain the `C` behavior in Bash? Thanks.

Edited:

I was curious about this behaviour, I can't accept a workaround that changes the order of the arguments. It should work just playing with the format string.

Edited:

E.g. think about GNU Bash source code internationalization. Very improbable without this feature.

Comment: There is currently a discussion about including this in the POSIX standard for the `printf` utility.  This, obviously, doesn't magically make it work in `bash`.

Comment: @Kusalananda can you link that discussion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make bash do it without invoking other processes by redefining printf as a function:

```bsh
printf() {  # add support for numbered conversion specifiers
    local -a args
    local opt=
    case $1 in
    -v) opt=-v$2; shift 2;;
    -*) opt=$1; shift;;
    esac
    local format=$1; shift
    while [[ $format =~ ((^|.*[^%])%)([0-9]+)\$(.*) ]]
    do
        args=("${!BASH_REMATCH[3]}" "${args[@]}")
        format=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
    done
    let ${#args[@]} && set -- "${args[@]}"
    builtin printf $opt "$format" "$@"
}
```

This works by replacing numbered conversion specifiers in the format string with unnumbered ones while using the numbers to select arguments for a modified argument list. If no numbered conversion specifiers are present, the printf builtin will see the function's arguments as-is. Should be a drop-in replacement with very little surprising behaviour.

The possibly surprising ordering in the statement that builds the new argument list, with new arguments pushed onto the front of the args[] array instead of being appended, is needed because bash regex matching is greedy; each time around the while loop, the numbered conversion specifier it finds will be the last one remaining in the format string.

Also note that the format string recycling that the printf builtin normally performs when passed more arguments than the format string contains conversion specifiers for doesn't happen when numbered conversion specifiers are present; arguments that don't correspond to a numbered specifier are simply ignored. Given that POSIX describes the mixing of numbered and unnumbered conversion specifiers as undefined, I think that's reasonable.

Comment: I appreciate this native approach but it does not work to me testing with `printf '%2$s %2$s %1%s %1%s' 'World' 'Hello'`

Comment: Try `printf '%2$s %2$s %1$s %1$s' 'World' 'Hello'` instead; when I do that I see output `Hello Hello World World` as expected. `%1%s` (possibly a typo?) isn't a valid conversion specifier. `%s` is, but I'm not sure the builtin `printf` parser will find it behind the `%1` and even if it did you'd be mixing numbered and unnumbered specifiers, which POSIX says is undefined.

Comment: Changed my solution to this answer because it's effective and 100% just Bash.

Comment: @ValerioBozz, it's got a few issues though: won't work with  `-v` if `$IFS` contains non-whitespace (`$opt` handling should be done with an array, expansions should be quoted).  It won't work for things like `printf '%2$s,%1$s\n' a b c d` (`c`, `d` ignored as already noted in the answer). It doesn't handle escaped `%`'s as in `printf '%%0$x %2$s,%1$s\n' a b` (unlikely to be a problem in practice though).

Comment: Thanks, Stéphane. I've edited the answer and modified the regex handling to fix the %% bug.

Comment: I still think simply dropping non-selected arguments is the most natural way to deal with them. Anybody who wants to do something different with them can modify their own instances of this function to implement their preferred behaviour.

Comment: The `IFS` issue wasn't real (bash doesn't word-split variable assignment statements) but since its `printf` builtin doesn't actually require the `-v` option and its variable name argument to be separate words, I removed `IFS` handling altogether to reduce confusion.

Comment: `$opt` needs to be passed bare to the `printf` builtin so that it disappears properly if not used instead of being parsed as an empty format string. In the pathological case of `IFS` including characters that would make `-vwhatever` get split after `$opt` is expanded, that split would have happened to the `printf` function's arguments before they ever arrived inside it.

Answer (score 7):

You can't with `bash`. the [POSIX specification of the `printf` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) doesn't support it either. You'd have to re-order the arguments by hand.

The `printf` (or `print -f`) builtins of `ksh93` and `zsh` support them though:

```
$ printf '%2$s%1$s\n' a b
ba
```

GNU `awk` or `perl` also support it, so if you have any of those installed, in `bash`, you could redefine `printf` as a function like:

```
printf() { zsh -c '"$0" "$@"' printf "$@"; }
```

or:

```
printf() { ksh93 -c '"$0" "$@"' printf "$@"; }
```

It would be more effort with `gawk` or `perl` however as `gawk` won't let you pass `ARGV` as is and neither `gawk` nor `perl` would expand the `\x` sequences (unless passed literally in their code in double quotes) and they don't support `%b` (an extension of the `printf` utility used to emulate the SysV `echo`).